# Prove the sequence of three real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

> If $a,b,c$ are non zero real numbers satisfying $$(ab+bc+ca)^3=abc(a+b+c)^3$$ then prove that $a,b,c$ are terms in $G.P$

My work:

I assumed that they are in $G.P$ and so assumed $b=ak$ and $c=ak^2$ for some arbitrary $k$. After that I expanded both sides of the equality and got the same results so that means the equality is true. But here's the twist!

Suppose the question was

> If $a,b,c$ are non zero real numbers satisfying $$(ab+bc+ca)^3=abc(a+b+c)^3$$ then the terms $a,b,c$ are in $G.P$ or $A.P$ or $H.P\:\:?$

Then what should be one's approach. Will expanding work here$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do $G.P$, $A.P$ and $H.P$ mean?

Comment: Oh, geometric, arithmetic and harmonic progression.

Comment: In fact, you have not even done the original problem correctly. You were asked to, "prove that $a,b,c$ are terms in $G.P$". You "assumed that they are in $G.P$ ... then expanded both sides of the equality and got the same results so that means the equality is true." So what you have actually done is prove that, "If $a,b,c$ are in G.P then they satisfy the equality. " But this doesn't answer the original question, because there could be $a,b,c$ *not in* G.P. which satisfy the original equality...

Comment: By your work you see, that any 3 numbers in geometric progression satisfy the stated relation. Your questions asks: are they in general in arithmetic or harmonic progression too? The answer is clearly: no. The geometric progression $a=1,b=2,c=4$ is easily seen to be neither arithmetic nor harmonic. Are there, however, geometric progressions that at the same time are arithmetic or/and harmonic? Yes, e.g. $a=b=c=1$, but it seems to me, that such sequences have to be necessarily trivial. This doesn't have much to do with your equation but rather with general properties of such progressions.

Comment: The so-called solution that you wrote is not even a true solution

Comment: I know that .....Adam already told me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you haven't really proved that the equation implies $a, b, c$ are in G.P., you have only shown the other way round.

Here is a **hint** to address the original problem,
$$(ab+bc+ca)^3-abc(a+b+c)^3=(ab-c^2)(bc-a^2)(ca-b^2)$$
Now you can show that if any of the terms on RHS is zero, that implies $a, b, c$ are in G.P.

Comment: The identity in variables $\,a,b,c\,$ is in Hall and Knight, _Higher Algebra_, 1957, page 439, "$23.\quad abc(\Sigma a)^3-(\Sigma bc)^3 = abc\Sigma a^3-\Sigma b^3c^3 = (a^2-bc)(b^2-ca)(c^2-ab).$"

Comment: what was your motivation behind this factorisation$?$

Comment: @abcdefu If $x,y,z$ are in GP (in that order), then $y^2=xz$ is known.  Hence one looks for such factors...

Answer (score 4):

Macavity has given a good answer for how to go about the original problem. To answer your original *question*,

> Suppose the question was
>
> If $a,b,c$ are non zero real numbers satisfying $$(ab+bc+ca)^3=abc(a+b+c)^3$$ then the terms $a,b,c$ are in $G.P$ or $A.P$ or $H.P\:\:?$
>
> Then what should be one's approach. Will expanding work here$?$

You start by trying to come up with counter-examples for each A.P., G.P. H.P, separately. It's not hard to come up with counter-examples for H.P and A.P. But once you struggle to come up with a counter-example for G.P., you might suspect it is true, so maybe you have a go at proving it is true, i.e. that $a,b,c$ *are* in G.P. . And then if you struggle too much with this, you go back to trying to find a counter-example. Then go back and forth between looking for a counter-example and trying to prove the affirmative. That's the way I do it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

We can think of the problem in terms of polynomials too. Assume that $a, b, c$ are the roots of the cubic polynomial '$ P(x) = x^3 + ux^2 + vx + w$. We get
$$-u = a+b+c$$
$$v = ab+bc+ca$$
$$-w = abc$$
Substituting these in the original condition, we have
$$v^3 = (-w)(-u)^3 = wu^3$$ or
$$ w = \frac{v^3}{u^3}$$
$$P(x) = x^3 + ux^2 + vx +\frac{v^3}{u^3} = (x^3 + \frac{v^3}{u^3}) + (ux^2 + vx) $$
$$= (x + \frac{v}{u})(x^2 + \frac{v^2}{u^2} - \frac{v}{u}x) + ux(x+\frac{v}{u}) $$
This shows $\frac{-v}{u}$ is a root of the P(x). The product of three roots is $-w = \frac{-v^3}{u^3}$. So the product of the other two roots is $\frac{v^2}{u^2}$. We get that square of one root is product of other two and they must be in a G.P.

Comment: Sorry for any mistake. This is my first time posting a solution on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question, in dealing with relations between three members of a progression for equations such as $ \ (ab+bc+ca)^3 \ = \ abc·(a+b+c)^3 \ \ , \ $ it can be useful to take, say, $ \ b \ $ as the "middle" member and write the other two in terms of it.

For an arithmetic progression with a common difference of $ \ d \  \ , \ $ we have $ \ b - d \ , \ b \ , \ b + d \ \ . \ $ This leads to the putative equation
$$ [ \ (b-d)·b \ + \ b·(b+d) \ + \ (b-d)·(b+d) \ ]^3 \ \ =^{?} \ \ (b-d)·b·(b+d)·(3b)^3 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ [ \ 3b^2  \ - \  d^2 \ ]^3 \ \ \neq \ \ 27·b^4·(b^2 - d^2) \ \ .  $$
We see at once that this is not an equation, since, as a "binomial-cube", the left side must have four terms when "expanded", including powers of $ \ d \ $ as high as $ \ 6 \ \ , \ $ which are clearly not present on the right side.  (The two sides are only equal for $ \ d \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ ] $  The members of a harmonic progression produce a similar situation.  With the members $ \ \frac{1}{\beta - d} \ , \ b = \frac{1}{\beta} \ , \ \frac{1}{\beta + d} \ \ , \ $ we would need to have
$$ [ \ (\beta-d)^{-1}·\beta^{-1} \ + \ \beta^{-1}·(\beta+d)^{-1} \ + \ (\beta-d)^{-1}·(\beta+d)^{-1} \ ]^3 $$ $$ =^{?} \ \ (\beta -d)^{-1}·\beta^{-1}·(\beta+d)^{-1}·[ \ (\beta -d)^{-1}  + \beta^{-1} + (\beta+d)^{-1} \ ]^3 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left[ \ \frac{3·\beta}{\beta \ · \ (\beta^2   -   d^2)} \ \right]^3 \ \ \neq \ \ \frac{1}{\beta  ·  (\beta^2   -   d^2)} \  \ · \ \left[ \ \frac{3·\beta^2  \ - \  d^2}{\beta  ·  (\beta^2   -   d^2)} \ \right]^3 \ \ , $$
which is also evidently not an equation for $ \ d \ \neq \ 0 \ \ . $

On the other hand, the members $ \ \frac{b}{r} \ , \ b \ , \ br \ $ of a geometric progression with common ratio $ \ r \ $ produces
$$ \left[ \ \frac{b}{r}·b \ + \ b·br \ + \ \frac{b}{r}·br \ \right]^3 \ \ =^{?} \ \ \left( \ \frac{b}{r} \ · \ b \ · \ br \ \right) \ · \ \left[ \ \frac{b}{r} \ + \ b \ + \ br \ \right]^3 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   (b^2)^3 \ · \ \left[ \ \frac{1}{r}  \ + \ 1 \ + \  r \ \right]^3 \ \ =^{!} \ \ b^3 \ · \ b^3    ·   \left[ \ \frac{1}{r} \ + \ 1 \ + \ r \ \right]^3   $$
as you found by doing something also this line (although we can observe the equality or inequalities without expanding the implied multinomials).

$$ \ \ $$

I agree that **Macavity**'s factorization is probably the most satisfying argument for showing that a geometric progression needs to be present among some ordering of the three numbers in order to satisfy the equation (addressing the original problem).  I had considered dividing out a factor of $ \ abc \ $ from the equation to obtain
$$   \left( \  b \ + \  c \ + \ \frac{b}{a}·c  \ \right)·\left( \ a  \ + \  c \ + \ \frac{a}{b}·c \ \right)·\left( \ a  \ + \  b \ + \ \frac{a}{c}·b \ \right) \ \ = \ \  (a \ + \ b \ + \ c)^3  \ \ . $$
One could make a glib argument that each factor of the left side must match one of the three identical factors on the right side, giving us $ \ \frac{b}{a}·c  \ = \ a \ \Rightarrow \ a^2 \ = \ bc \ \ , \ $ and similarly, $ \ b^2 \ = \ ac \ \ , \  c^2 \ = \ ab \   , \ $ so that a geometric progression must be present among some ordering of $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ c \ \ . $  However, this is only really convincing if $ \ a + b + c \ $ is a prime integer; otherwise, it is difficult to be persuasive that the equality of the two products  permits us to "match factors" in that way.